# monitoring stock prices on yahoo finance efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently trying to get live stock prices using the beautifulsoup and requests library from the yahoo finance website. I'm currently finding that the bottleneck for speed is that the request for the webpage takes around 0.5 seconds on average. Below is my code and output

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests
import time

# transform percent text into numerical (float) value
def process_percent_change(percent_text):
    processed_text = []
    for c in percent_text:
        if c == '.' or c == '+' or c == '-' or  c.isdigit():
            processed_text.append(c)
    if processed_text[0] == '-':
        return -float("".join(processed_text[1:]))
    else:
        return float("".join(processed_text[1:]))


# parse most current ticker data from beautiful soup object
def get_current_data():
    # define the page to be parsed for data
    spy_link = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY&.tsrc=fin-srch" # yahoo finance link to SPY etf info
    webpage_start = time.time()
    page = requests.get(spy_link).text
    webpage_end = time.time()

    webpage_time = webpage_end-webpage_start
    print("webpage get time: {}".format(webpage_time))

    parse_start = time.time()
    strainer = SoupStrainer('div', attrs = {'data-reactid': '30'}) # only get relevant div info
    data_element = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml', parse_only=strainer)

    current_data = {}

    # store current data inside a dictionary
    current_data["current_price"] = float(data_element.find('span', attrs={"data-reactid": "32"}).text)
    change = data_element.find('span', attrs={"data-reactid": "33"}).text.split()
    current_data["value_change"] = float(change[0])
    current_data["percent_change"] = process_percent_change(change[1])
    parse_end = time.time()

    parse_time = parse_end-parse_start

    print("parse time: {}".format(parse_time))
    # return data to be used
    return current_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_data = get_current_data()
```

```
webpage get time: 0.42667412757873535
parse time: 0.05974388122558594
```

What I want to do is either speed up the request or find a more efficient way of monitoring the website for changes. I've noticed that after loading the website in my browser that the price will change without having to refresh the page. Here is a gif example for what I mean:
https://media.giphy.com/media/nZmbqDeu7rWT2vmrks/giphy.gif

Here's a link to the specific yahoo finance page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY?p=SPY&.tsrc=fin-srch

Is there a way to monitor the stock price such as in the gif/web browser example? If there isn't, is there a way to speed up requests (without buying a faster connection)?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a reasonable time for what you are doing (downloading and parsing **a webpage**).

In real I think that 0.4s should be enough for monitoring, but if you really need to have an higher update frequency (ie. you have got some new crazy trading algorithm) you can:

- Try to **parse a more lightweight page**. (But you need to find one!)
- Create a **pool of thread** performing many requests at the same time. You should note that this behaviour could lead to a violation of yahoo ToS and restrictions on your account/ip could be applied.
- Use any sort of **market API** (free or payed) to avoid downloading an entire webpage and all its dependencies when you can just have something like a 20byte json (or similar) message. Also in this case you should read about the max pooling frequency you can use.
- **Use Selenium** and perform just 1 connection to the webpage. When you detect any changes in the div you are interested in you get the updated value.